# Evaluation of limits for a recursive sequence with different $a_0$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I have a recursive sequence, namely $a_{n+1} = f(a_n)$, where $f(x)=x-x^2$.

This sequence has a different behaviour when evaluated at different starting points $a_0$. If $a_0\gt1\lor a_0\lt0$ the sequence is not bounded and monotonic, while if $0\le a_0 \le 1$ it has limit $0$.

I can prove it is always downward monotonic, but I do not know how to show that it is not bounded in one case while bounded in the other.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1-a_n$$if $a_0<0$, then $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}>1$.$$$$if $0<a_0<1$, the  $ 0<\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1$.$$$$if $a_0>1$, then $a_1=a_0(1-a_0)<0$, then $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}>1$ when $n \geq 1$.$$$$The results can be obtained easily with geometric sequence